# font-face not working in any browser

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, font-face, stylus

I am facing trouble with rendering fonts for my react application. I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I am using font-face in my project. This is my font.styl file

All the fonts are in public directory. 
[image]

font.styl

```
@font-face
    font-family 'museo_sans700'
    src url('/public/fonts/museosans_0-webfont.woff2') format('woff2')
        url('/public/fonts/museosans_0-webfont.woff') format('woff')
    font-weight normal
    font-style normal

@font-face
    font-family 'museo_sans300'
    src url('/public/fonts/museosans-300-webfont.woff2') format('woff2')
        url('/public/fonts/museosans-300-webfont.woff') format('woff')
    font-weight normal
    font-style normal

@font-face
    font-family 'museo_sans500'
    src url('/public/fonts/museosans-webfont.woff2') format('woff2')
        url('/public/fonts/museosans-webfont.woff') format('woff')
    font-weight normal
    font-style normal

@font-face
    font-family 'montserratregular'
    src url('/public/fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2')
        url('/public/fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff')
    font-weight normal
    font-style normal
```

And this is my base.styl

```
@import './bs-custom.styl'
@import './fonts.styl'

html
    width 100%
    height 100%

body
    width 100vw
    min-height 100vh
    transition all 0.2s ease
    background-color #F0F0F0

    color theme_text
    font-size 14px
    font-weight 400
    font-family museo500

    overflow hidden
```

This is the loader I am using in config file

```
{
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
            },
```

Fonts are not showing up but.

Answer (score 0):

I got the bug in that. I was missing a comma after src url(...)

```
 src url('/public/fonts/museosans_0-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('/public/fonts/museosans_0-webfont.woff') format('woff')
```